# Unit Test Imported Modules when A Global Function Call will Fail

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, python-import

I am trying to mock a session created in a test by an import. I have two files:

/lib/module.py

```
import boto3
session = boto3.session()
```

/tests/test.py

```
from lib.module import test_func
test_function():
    assert test_func()
```

My testing environment fails on import from the session call without credentials. How can I mock the import/session to prevent failure in the testing environment?

Answer (score 0):

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch, Mock
from lib.module import test_func

class TestYourModule(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch('lib.module.boto3')
    def test_function(self, mock_boto3):
        # Create a mock session
        mock_session = Mock()
        mock_boto3.session.return_value = mock_session

        # Configure the mock session as needed
        # For example, you can set up mock client or resource objects
        mock_client = Mock()
        mock_session.client.return_value = mock_client

        # Call your function under test
        result = test_func()

        # Add your assertions based on the expected behavior of test_func
        self.assertEqual(result, expected_result)
```

In this code, im using `unittest.mock.patch` to replace the `boto3` import in the `lib.module` with a mock object. Then, we create a mock session and configure it as needed for your test case. Finally, you can call your `test_func` and make assertions based on the expected behavior.

This approach allows you to mock the `boto3` session and its behavior, so you don't need real credentials.